# Map mixed arrays of elements from XML to a model

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have an XML element that has lists of 2 types of child elements that are mixed. This precludes me from using lists directly.

For example, let's say I have XML like this:

```
<country>
    <city>...</city>
    <village>...</village>
    <village>...</village>
    <city>...</city>
    <village>...</village>
</country>
```

Instead of this:

```
<country>
    <cities>
        <city>...</city>
        <city>...</city>
    </cities>
    <villages>
        <village>...</village>
        <village>...</village>
        <village>...</village>
    </villages>
</country>
```

And I want to map it to this model:

```
public class Country
{
    public List<string> Cities { get; set; }
    public List<string> Villages { get; set; }
}
```

This would be easy with the second example but how do I do it for the first?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can without implementing `IXmlSerializable` manually. If you have to keep the XML in that form, then the model would need to look something like this:

```
[XmlRoot("country")]
public class Country
{
    [XmlElement("city", typeof(City))]
    [XmlElement("village", typeof(Village))]
    public List<object> CitiesAndVillages { get; set; }    
}

public class City
{
    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Village
{
    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OERDpT) for a demo. Note you could also use a single `List<string>` with an associated [choice identifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlchoiceidentifierattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), but I I usually prefer this sort of approach.

One further tip for this sort of problem is to copy your XML to the clipboard and use `Edit |> Paste Special |> Paste XML As Classes` in Visual Studio. This magically generates some classes that will deserialise the given XML.

Comment: You are right. I have to deserialize the output of third party modules and I don't have control over its form.